# CRTP with full template specialization

Tags: c++

Why is the following code is not correct?

```
template <typename T>
class B {
public:
    auto foo() -> decltype(static_cast<T*>(this)->foo()) {
        return static_cast<T*>(this)->foo();
    }
};
    
template <typename X>
class A: public B<A<X>> {
public:
    X foo();
};
    
template <>
class A<int>: public B<A<int>> {
public:
    int foo();
};
```

Compiler gives the following error (highlighting `decltype(static_cast<T*>(this)->foo())` part):

```
static_cast from 'B<A<int>> *' to 'A<int> *', which are not related by inheritance, is not allowed
in instantiation of template class B<A<int>> requested here
'A' is incomplete
'B' is incomplete
```

Comment: fwiw, you get almost identical error without the specialization: https://godbolt.org/z/zf14c4

Comment: It wouldn't work either if there were no specialization - at the time of instantiating B<X> A<X> is incomplete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue with CRTP, is that derived is incomplete from CRTP.

So

```
-> decltype(static_cast<T*>(this)->foo())
```

is problematic for 2 reasons, as `T` is incomplete:

- it is not yet derived class of `B<T>`, `std::declval<T>().foo()` might solve that issue.
- `T::foo` is not yet declared.

Possible solution is to get rid of explicit return type, and use just `auto` which is delayed to method instantiation.

```
template <typename T>
class B {
public:
    auto foo()
    {
        return static_cast<T*>(this)->foo();
    }
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/da737n)

Comment: `decltype(auto)` as return type rather ?

Comment: @puio: Possible, for OP example `auto` is sufficient.